# Nested redo group with NSUndoManager

Tags: nested, undo-redo, nsundomanager

Suppose I have two atomic object methods `operation1` and `operation2`, that register their own undo actions to `undoManager`. If I make bulk `operation3`, that calls previous two operations and groups undo callbacks with `beginUndoGrouping/endUndoGrouping`, when undoing, `NSUndoManager` doesn't group redo actions. How to make `NSUndoManager` map undo group to redo group?

Sample code:

```
- (void)operation3
{
    [undoManager beginUndoGrouping];
    [self operation1]; // [undoManager setActionName:@"op1"];
    [self operation2]; // [undoManager setActionName:@"op2"];
    [undoManager endUndoGrouping];
    [undoManager setActionName:@"op3"];
    // call operation3 -> "Edit - Undo op3" -- OK
    // press Command+Z -> "Edit - Redo op1" -- not OK
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set the action name again during the undo. I think you set only "op1" during the undo.

Comment: It seems that my intention to combine undoable actions in compound methods is wrong: I ended up writing lots of boilerplate code just to make `undo/redo` composite actions stack in right order.